# Need advice on samba shares and permissions

Tags: 10.04, permissions, samba

I'm trying to achieve the following, in order to access samba shares from a Windows XP box:

Live users get a home directory which can be accessed with full permissions through samba if they are authenticated as the owner. I have this working with the following samba config settings:

```
####### Authentication #######

   security = user
   encrypt passwords = yes
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdate$
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user

####### Shares #######

[homes]
   comment = %S
   path = /home/%S
   allow hosts = 127. 192.168.1.
   valid users = %S
   browseable = yes
   writable = yes
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
```

This is pretty much working a expected, apart from the right permissions being set when I create files and directories. But I read some other answers that talk about tinkering with different `mask` variants. So I'll probably get that fixed, so: so far so good.

What I'd like to have additionally, is another folder (`music`) that can be accessed with full permissions by me (let's say `myusername`), and only read permissions by guests (that don't need to authenticate to access these folders).

I created a group called `music` and a user called `music` with a home directory `/home/music`, and also added `myusername` to the group `music`. Then I tried the following samba config:

```
[music]
   comment = %S
   path = /home/music
   allow hosts = 127. 192.168.1.
   browsable = yes
   writable = yes
   read list = @music
   write list = myusername
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
```

However, logging in on this samba directory as `myusername` from Windows XP didn't let me create files and/or directories. Could this be because of conflicts with the `[homes]` setting (since it is already referring to directories in `/home` as well)? Or am I misunderstanding the principles of user/group permissions?

Apart from that, I also started thinking: do I even *need* to create the group and user `music` to begin with? It appears to be a bit redundant when they wouldn't have write access to begin with anyway. Couldn't I simply create the directory `/home/music` with `sudo` (or another suggestion perhaps?), and use the above samba settings.

Whichever way, I *do* like to have this folder on the `/home` partition (it's on a separate HDD being the only partition on that HDD). I consider this kind of as my 'data' partition, not merely 'user data'. Or is that frowned upon, in general?

As you can see, I'm having a bit of difficulty with thinking of a good permissions strategy *and* coming up with the right samba config setting.

Could you shed some light on how I could best achieve what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so thus far I've managed to, kind of, get what I wanted by creating a directory in `myusername` called `music`. I deleted the group and user `music` (and its home directory) altogether.

So now my home structure is:

```
- /home
   - /myusername
     - /music
   - /otherusername
   - /andanotherusername
```

And I managed to get fully accessible user home directories with (as I already had):

```
[homes]
   comment = %S
   path = /home/%S
   allow hosts = 127. 192.168.1.
   valid users = %S
   browseable = no
   writable = yes
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
```

And a directory `music` being read only for guests and fully accessible for `myusername` with:

```
[music]
   comment = %S
   path = /home/myusername/music
   allow hosts = 127. 192.168.1.
   browsable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   guest account = nobody
   read list = nobody
   write list = myusername
   create mask = 0755
   directory mask = 0700
```

It still feels a bit weird to have to have a subdirectory in the `myusername` home directory though. Preferably I'd like to have the `music` directory not being tied to myself.

I wanted to answer my own question as a suggestion for others who might want to achieve similar things.

I'd still welcome better suggestions though.